# Can a sampling based method estimate how many species exist?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, estimation, sampling, biology

I've got in to a bit of a debate online and I'm hoping some people here can help clear it up.
The position I'm arguing against is "It's impossible even come up with a ballpark estimate for how many species exist."

My logic is:

1. Estimating the total number of species (known and unknown) can be treated as an estimation of distinct values problem.
2. Sampling based estimators can be used to estimate the number of distinct values.

Therefor it's possible to estimate the total number of species.

Is my logic sound?

Answer (score 1):

For estimating the number of species in a specific habitat, look at:

http://viceroy.eeb.uconn.edu/estimates/

Especially look at Anna Chao's work, which is really quite brilliant.  If you observe a total of $S$ species, then a rather reliable lower bound on the number of species you have not observed is $n_1^2/(2n_2)$, where $n_1$ is the number of species observed once, and $n_2$ is the number of species observed twice.

I also co-authored papers on this subject: 
http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/class-novel.html
http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/class-bayesian.html
http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/schmidt-paper.html
The last paper was published, and is based on Chao's work.

Answer (score 0):

If all species were equally abundant and easy to catch, and assuming you can recognize an organism as belonging to a new species when you catch it, then you could use such estimators.  But if there are lots of very rare species that would have very low probabilities of showing up in samples, there's no way to estimate that (unless you catch everything!).

Comment: Sample based estimators don't rely on equal abundance. I think we have also think high enough sample of endangered/rare species to estimate roughly how common they are. 

Wrongly identifying species is certainly going to be a factor but I'm sure there are studies which estimate that.

The hard to catch species are probably the factor which make this the hardest. I can't see a way around that.

Comment: Not necessarily equal abundance, but the very rare ones are a problem.  Suppose e.g. you have $N$ species so rare that together they make up much less than $1/M$ of the total population, and you take a sample of $M$ individuals.  Then with high probability none of these rare species will be represented in your sample.  So how could you possibly guess what $N$ is?

Comment: We already have a statistically significant sample of rare species (10s - 100s of individuals) so I think this would be somewhat accessible (admittedly we knew about many of these before they became rare which will skew the statistics). 

The effects of inbreeding and the instability of vlow populations also mean that species can't exist in this state for long periods of time so as a result I think ultra-rare species could only account for a tiny percentage of the whole.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very intriguing question.

It shares resemblance to a heated discussion over at the [Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).  Here I summarize from [that post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13665/number-of-species-is-restricted-by-number-of-genome-combinations).

To tie the relevance to *your* specific question, the **answer** I describe here is a conjecture about: "Upper limit to possible number of species that can exist", rather than a ballpark value.

***Proposed Conjecture***

> The maximum number of species must be limited by the maximum
>   combinatorial/permutational space that can be occupied by DNA. Thus if
>   there is a maximum physical genome size this is what will determine
>   the maximum number of species that can possibly exist.

***Explanation***

For example, lets say the maximum number of DNA base pairs able to fit in a genome was 3, each can be one of either {A,G,T,C}. Then there are 4^3 = 64 possible combinations of genomes. Thus there can only be 64 possible distinct species. Extrapolate to genome sizes of X, then there are 4^X possible species that can possibly exist.

***Formulation***

The maximum number of possible species < 4^X

Comment: While true, it is not useful.  Most estimates I have seen for the number of species in the world are around tens of millions, maybe hundreds of millions.  We know $X$ is far larger than $20$, and $4^{20} \gt 1$ trillion

Comment: @Ross Millikan Very fair, perhaps It would be interesting though, to map as many available genome sequences onto a discrete "potential genome space" and "fill in the gaps" through interpolation - this could potentially lead to useful estimations of a ballpark figure. Surely... knowing a physical upper limit poses some benefit (e.g. truncated statistical distributions at the upper tail)

Comment: When the mismatch is *so* large I don't think it helps at all.  As hinted in the Biology thread, you can make a huge improvement to $20^{(X/3)}$ by considering proteins, but that is still an enormous number, far larger than anything of interest.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-S I cannot post on your answer, but thank you very much for the suggested reading. Fascinating stuff.

Comment: The trouble is, most DNA sequences are going to be non-viable.  And by most, I mean that the percentage of DNA sequences that are anything close to being viable is probably some improbably small number like 1 divided by the numbers of protons in the universe.  You have to have a lot of very basic machinery coded into the DNA (like creating the proteins that decode the DNA into proteins) if it is going to be viable.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue yes and no.

Yes:  I saw the claim in [E. O. Wilson's Biodiversity](http://www.nap.edu/catalog.php?record_id=989) that the unknown species are dominated by insects in the rain forest.  If you believe this, you can essentially use sample-recapture techniques.  I have read that it is standard practice to set off a gas bomb by a tree and count/ID everything that falls out.  Do this for a bunch of trees and you can get a distribution of new species.  Say every time you sample a different tree of the same species you get five new insect species, but when you had sampled half as many as today you were finding ten.  Now try a new species of tree and find a hundred.  You can use this (over many species of trees) to estimate a distribution.

No: do we believe that claim?  Think about the relatively recent discovery of the hydrothermal vents in the ocean and the life around them.  There is new work at microscopic life buried in the rocks and soil-and there is a *lot* of volume there.  The rain forest work can give a lower bound, but there might be some large population we have missed entirely.